# ERROR : Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, dart

I recently started android app development and I am working with flutter on android studio. On clicking on RUN I get the following error. Can anyone suggest me a solution?

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi 7A in debug mode...
```

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 in C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 28 in C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 28 not accepted.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
  >    build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3
  >    platforms;android-28 Android SDK Platform 28
  >   To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  >   Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

  Using Android SDK: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54510465/finished-with-error-gradle-task-assembledebug-failed-with-exit-code-1)

Comment: sdkmanager.bat --licenses <--Run this command in terminal and press y in all the options.

Comment: Thank you Sanket, it worked.