# The code doesn't work: void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: Center(child: Text('Hello World'))));

Tags: android, flutter

(Sorry for my poor English)
The first picture is from a video, the second one is mine.
In the first picture you can see that the result of the her coding is "hello world"
But nothing happened to mine.
What's wrong with my coding?
[Picture one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMnpl.png)

[Picture two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXuAP.png)

Flutter doctor:
C:\src\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat doctor --verbose
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.900], locale zh-TW)
• Flutter version 1.17.2 at C:\src\flutter\flutter
• Framework revision 5f21edf8b6 (4 weeks ago), 2020-05-28 12:44:12 -0700
• Engine revision b851c71829
• Dart version 2.8.3

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\MSINB\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
• Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin version 46.0.2
• Dart plugin version 193.7361
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] Connected device (1 available)
• Android SDK built for x86 64 • emulator-5554 • android-x64 • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Something is wron with your `flutter` setup, what happens when you run `flutter doctor`?

Comment: Can you add the output of flutter doctor?

Comment: ! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: @JoshuaChang run: `flutter doctor --android-licenses` . Also check your env variables. According to the error `C:\  is not a ...`  appears like error in the path of Flutter sdk in env variables.

Comment: Microsoft Windows [版本 10.0.18362.900]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. 著作權所有，並保留一切權利。

C:\Users\MSINB>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.900], locale zh-TW)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.

Comment: C:\Users\MSINB>flutter doctor --android-licenses
Warning: File C:\Users\MSINB\.android\repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
6 of 7 SDK package licenses not accepted. 100% Computing updates...
Review licenses that have not been accepted (y/N)? 要終止批次工作嗎 (Y/N)?
^C

Answer (score 0):

There may be problem with gradle, installisation. You could find answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54510465/finished-with-error-gradle-task-assembledebug-failed-with-exit-code-1).

Answer (score 0):

Just add a Scaffold as `home: Scaffold` and the Center as `body: Center`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Hello World'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Always consider adding explanation about the code and the part of problem the code solves. It will help everyone reading the answer. All efforts are appreciated. Keep answering.