# A problem occurred evaluating project ':honeywell_scanner'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

The plugin `flutter_absolute_path` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.
If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding: https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/ddo/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/honeywell_scanner-3.2.0+13/android/build.gradle' line: 45

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':honeywell_scanner'.
> Project with path ':honeywell' could not be found in project ':honeywell_scanner'.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

BUILD FAILED in 11s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54510465/12838877   have you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

add this in `android/setting.gradle`

```
include ':app' // it should be there

include ':honeywell' // add this
```